# Parse a string representation of javascript without storing a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

There is a scenario where I let a client to insert a JavaScript script that should be sent my server. Actually, this script (well, should..) will export some object.

So the frontend code is something like this:

```html
 <form action="/blabla.js" method="post">
  <textarea>
</form>
```

Then the frontend sends the input of the `<textarea />` to the server.
A typical input will be something like:

```js
module.exports = {
    glagla: {
        blabla: 2
    },
};
```

The frontend will send this script, as a string, to a server.

Next step is the server needs to parse this string.

So right now, for example with `express` package it should look like:

```js
import fs from 'fs';

const handler = async (req, res) => {
    const input = req.body.script;

    await fs.promises.writeFile('./somewhere.js', req.body.script);
    
    const parsedObject = require('./somewhere.js');
}
```

I'm trying to not use the file system, but cannot find a way to do so.
I there a pure way, without using the file system to parse such a script in JS?

---

I think this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2 is the solution.

Comment: You can use `Function` to create function from string. But be careful while running code that you received from client side... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: @tarkh
Can you post an answer and show how using this leads to a result of an object representing the exported object of the script? Like the example in my question

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't need to use `module.exports` for this, because you dont need to create file and then include it in the code with `require`. You can pass just function body:

```js
// String from frontend, which must
// contain function body
const strFn = 'return { glagla: { blabla: 2 }}';

// Create function from string
const obj = new Function(strFn);

// Run created function and access
// property of returned object
console.log(obj().glagla.blabla);
```

But keep in mind, that this is pretty risky, because user can pass anything from frontend to your backend to run.

If you need to pass only object with it's properties and values, it's better to utilize JSON for this purpose:

```js
// Object on frontend side
const frontendObj = { glagla: { blabla: 2 }};

// While on frontend, convert object
// in to the JSON string
const strJSON = JSON.stringify(frontendObj);

//
// Then send this string to the server
//

// On server side parse received JSON
// string in to the JS object
const obj = JSON.parse(strJSON);

// Now you can access property of
// returned object
console.log(obj.glagla.blabla);
```

Comment: I want the script to include `module.exports = ...` so that's the problem. That is why I should and must use `vm2` package.